# Add custom .efi to grub menu

Tags: boot, grub, uefi

I learned about baremetal programming and created a simple pong game.

My linux is on a drive at /dev/sda. I placed the .efi file for pong on a drive at /dev/sdb, then efi/boot/bootx64.efi on this drive

I can access it and play pong by selecting the right boot device (On startup, I press del to enter boot menu. If i select the first drive I boot on grub, then linux. If I select the second drive, it takes me to the pong game)

Now, how can I make grub aware of this boot option, so that I could boot on /dev/sda, see grub, then choose linux or pong?

`update-grub` do not detect the pong game. (Yet, it detects a windows boot loader on /dev/sdc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got inspiration from the existing grub file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to create my entry.
In the end it looks like :

```
menuentry 'Pong' $menuentry_id_option 'play pong' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7a844a6a-9734-49a4-881d-662251c39cc3
    chainloader /my/custom/path/Pong.efi
}
```

With `part_gpt` and `ntfs` which are the partition table type and the file format. `search` will look the the drive with given UUID. And `chainloader` will select the .efi file to boot on that drive.

Finally, I added this entry not to `grub.cfg` but to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` so that programs like `update_grub` will keep this configuration. (Nb: Under linux mint 21)

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify grub's config. Go to /boot/grub/grub.conf.

Look there for the windows section of /dev/hdc, do exactly as it is for /dev/hdb.

```
# You should have already something like
title Windows         
set root=(hd2,0)         
chainloader +1

# Add 
title Game         
set root=(hd1,0)         
chainloader +1
```

The `root` will tell grub which drive, which partition on the drive to use.

The `chainloader` will tell grub to go directly to actual MBR of the drive. Since you can boot from your drive by using BIOS loaders - your MBR is already set correctly.

for more info: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html

Comment: Thanks. The windows part was a menuentry so a bit more complicated. I ended up copying it's content : `menuentry 'Pong' $menuentry_id_option 'play pong' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ntfs
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3D899484509A06C4
        chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
}
`. Chainloader +1 did not work.